# MySQL optimization : index choice WHERE vs JOIN

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a specific query where I want to LEFT JOIN on part of (specific date) the main table `tableA`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE date='2016-04-04') a 
LEFT JOIN tableB b 
ON a.columnA= b.columnB
```

Some table stats:

```
tableA: ~1m rows
tableA where date='2016-04-04': 46k rows
tableB: 62k rows
```

What is the optimal index(es) to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my experiments and results:

**No Index**

```
Query took 130.0157 seconds.
```

**Index on WHERE variable (date in TableA)**

```
Query took 111.722 seconds.
```

**Index on JOIN variable (columnA in TableA and columnB in TableB)**

```
Query took 10.578 seconds.
```

**Index on JOIN and WHERE variable (one index on columnA, another date in TableA and columnB in TableB)**

```
Query took 8.327 seconds.
```

So optimal choice for this case:

```
columnA index and columnB index will be used in JOIN key to improve **a lot**
date index will be used in WHERE key to improve **a bit**
```

Comment: `10s --> 8s ` mean `20%` time reduction, that is more than `**a bit**`

Comment: it is a bit compared to >90% on the join clause. But yeah, it is significative

Comment: Please try the composite index and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Probably even better would be one composite index on TableA for

```
 (date, columnA)
```

And index on TableB for

```
(columnB)
```

Comment: it is about the same (8.5s) but what is the theory behind your answer? Why did you think a joint index is better than 2 separates ones? They are used separately in the query (not in the same clause)

Comment: Because if you use a composite index and find `date` you already get `columnA`, if you use two index you need to search in one index, and then perform a lookup to find the other value. But the problem is the columnA is used on the outside query so looks like doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to replace `*` by the list of the columns you actually need.  This is especially helpful if there are `TEXT` columns that you don't need.

If you don't need `LEFT`, get rid of it.  That way, the optimizer may choose to start with tableB.  Currently, that option is *probably* prohibited.

```
tableA:  INDEX(date)
tableB:  INDEX(columnB)
```

`(date, columnA)` will not help any because the query will simply go for all of `*`.

`(columnA)` would be useful only if `LEFT` were removed.  Note:  "Nested Loop Join" goes one way or the other.  That is, you need an index on the second of the tables; having the corresponding index on the other side of the `JOIN` is not useful.

Did you run your timings twice?  The first time would populate cache; the second time would save the I/O.  Consider only the second.

Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for further discussion.